# How machine learning can help in predicting defect prone modules in applications before testing?

Tags: test-management, metrics, test-planning, data-analysis, static-analysis

I have looked and read in the internet that using static code analysis data, we can predict what modules in the application are defect prone. When I try to imagine of dataset,it is getting difficult to fit it as 2 dimensional. Since each build can have many modules and for each module we will be having source code metrics and defects count. My doubts are

1. Can we some how build a meaningful 2D dataset for analysis (like
   regression) and prediction ?
2. Is it just a theory or machine learning is being actually leveraged for this ? If yes, what techniques/use cases are currently under use ?
3. What are the other practical factors that needs to be considered for defect prediction analysis and can we collect them in reality ?

It will be very helpful if you could point out some detailed articles on this,if any.

PS: I am posting this here because people with great expertise in testing can only advise on where to look at for defects.

Answer (score 1):

Have a graph with number of bugs on the left vertical y axis

I would then have lines for factors that are relevant, e.g. lines of code, number of statements, line length, number of variables, global variables, etc.  You could also have a formula that multiplies them together to give one line.

I would stay away from trying to do multi-dimensional models unless you have the experience and knowledge needed and have already done this with a 2d model.  The details for 3d are important and don't fit well into a Stack Exchange question.

Answer (score 1):

#### Thoughts on error-prone modules detection

One line of "defect prone modules" analysis may use the *code complexity analysis* to classify a module as "error-prone" or not. This would be based on the fact that a *more complex code tend to have more potential bugs*.

There are several metrics in the code complexity analysis that we can use as parameters for machine learning algorithms:

- [**Cyclomatic code complexity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) ([What does the 'cyclomatic complexity' of my code mean?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/101830/what-does-the-cyclomatic-complexity-of-my-code-mean)):

  > Cyclomatic complexity is a software metric (measurement) which is a quantitative *measure of the number of linearly independent paths through a program's source code*.
- [**Maintainability Index**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385914.aspx)

  > Maintainability Index calculates an index value between 0 and 100 that represents the relative ease of maintaining the code
- [**Lines of Code**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385914.aspx)

  > A very high count might indicate that a type or method is trying to do too much work and should be split up. It might also indicate that the type or method might be hard to maintain.

#### Existing projects

According to [Bug prediction at Google](http://google-engtools.blogspot.com/2011/12/bug-prediction-at-google.html) article, they've been successful in using the modified "Rahman" algorithm that was based on the *number of times a module has been changed*:

> We implemented the Rahman algorithm by creating a program that hooked
> into our source control system, and pulls out all the changes which
> had a bug attached to them. It looks at each bug number, and verifies
> with the bug-tracking database that it was really a bug, and filters
> out everything else, such as feature requests. It then looks at all
> the files that appeared in these changes, and filters out those that
> have been deleted and are no longer at HEAD. For each file, the number
> of bug-fixing changes it's been in is calculated, and we output the
> files which were ranked in the top 10%.

This article became an inspiration for the [`bugspots`](https://github.com/igrigorik/bugspots) and [`hotfiles`](https://bitbucket.org/benallard/hotfiles) projects.

There is also [`FixCache` project](https://github.com/SoftwareIntrospectionLab/FixCache) (not maintained).

There is also the [MAST group](http://mast-group.github.io/) (Machine learning techniques for the Analysis of Source code Text) which published several machine learning models and algorithms for source-code analysis. I don't see something specific to detecting tendencies to errors in source code, but there are some interesting and related algorithms.

More articles on the subject:

- [Use of Relative Code Churn Measures to Predict System Defect Density](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/icse05churn.pdf) (there are also a lot of articles mentioned and linked in the paper)
- [Static code analysis versus machine learning defect prediction](http://www.defectprediction.net/2015/12/static-code-analysis-versus-machine.html)

Comment: Interesting set of links.